# Invalid JWT error in uber sdk

Tags: android, uber-api

I am using SSO for logging in the user into uber through my app. Here's  my code:

```
SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                // mandatory
                .setClientId(AppConstants.UBER_CLIENT_ID)
                // required for enhanced button features
                .setServerToken(AppConstants.UBER_SERVER_TOKEN)
                // required scope for Ride Request Widget features
                .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE))
                // optional: set Sandbox as operating environment
                .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
                .build();

        UberSdk.initialize(config);

LoginCallback loginCallback = new LoginCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLoginCancel() {
            // User canceled login
            Log.i(TAG, "login cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
            // Error occurred during login
            Log.i(TAG, error.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "login failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
            // Successful login!  The AccessToken will have already been saved.
            Log.i(TAG, "login successful");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authorizationCode) {
            Log.i(TAG, authorizationCode);
        }
    };
    accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(this);
    loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager, loginCallback);
    loginManager.login(this);
```

I am getting Invalid_JWT. Whats the issue here. I have set PROFILE Scope in my uber dashboard as well.

Comment: Can you share more details about the android version and rider app version? We think the issue might be caused by a bad crypto package, but we need more details.

Comment: Solved it. Was problem related to my account

Comment: Can you answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889973/invalid-oauth2-credentials-in-uber-sdk-for-android